# Python list - del, insert, no. of assignments and time complexity

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

I'm wondering about how many assignments python makes during an insert on an arbitrary index and how many assignments is being made when deleting the first element del(list[0]). I'm a little bit confused since the time complexity for these 2 operations are O(n), n being the number of elements in the list, but when thinking about it I get it to be O(n-1).

**"Deleting an element in a list requires shifting all the following elements, and the same goes for insertion, so that these two operations are O(i) where i is the number of items after the item you deleted/inserted".**

Does this mean that if I have a list containing 99999 elements and I insert an element at index 20000 (spot 20001), python shifts the 79999 following elements i.e 79999 assignments? Or does the actual insertion also require an assignment i.e its a total of 80000 assignments?

The same question goes for deletion. If I have a list containing 100000 elements and I delete the first, does python need 99999 assignments for the shifts or 100000?

Comment: Do you really care if it's 79999 or 80000? If you want to be accurate, the complexity is actually `O(n-i+1)`, where `i` is the index you're deleting/inserting. The thing is: Nobody cares. It's too specific. The whole point of time complexity analysis is to find out how fast the algorithm is with _large_ numbers. Numbers so large that +1 or -1 doesn't make a difference.

Comment: "Big O" notation deliberately doesn't include the 'detail' e.g. if a function works on a list of size n and does n-1 operations, it's still O(n), and not O(n-1). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation